# Set Crystal Reports Jet database password programmatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, crystal-reports, ms-access-2007

I don't know how to programmatically create Crystal Reports OLE DB (ADO) connection with provider Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine like what I did in this image

[OLE DB (ADO)](http://oi61.tinypic.com/muud6a.jpg)

I need to specify Jet Database password programmatically [Jet Database Password](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2ql4cp5.jpg)

Note : when I use

```
Dim reportDocument As New ReportDocument()    
reportDocument.Load(" MY REPORT PATH ")
reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("Admin","Password")
```

this method sets password from "Jet Database Password" image ... I don't need to set password I need to set Jet database password

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue. The accepted answer has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 2):

I am using following code to pass the jet database password using crystal reports 13 API: (m_repDoc is the report object)

```
TableLogOnInfo logonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
foreach (Table table in m_repDoc.Database.Tables)
{
    logonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
    logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = server; // path to database file

    logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.LogonProperties.Add(new NameValuePair2(
          "Jet OLEDB:Database Password", password)); // Your jet database password

    table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo);
}
```

Of course this is written nowhere in the manuals/help files. It should also work if you are using subreports.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
        {

            ReportDocument r = new ReportDocument();               
            r.Load(path + rptname);


            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ISCDReportClientDocument boReportClientDocument;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.Database boDatabase;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.Tables boTables;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseController boDatabaseController;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo boConnectionInfo;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag boAttributesPropertyBag;
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag boLogonPropertyBag;

            boReportClientDocument = r.ReportClientDocument;
            boDatabaseController = boReportClientDocument.DatabaseController;
            boDatabase = boDatabaseController.Database;
            boTables = boDatabase.Tables;

            foreach (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ISCRTable boTableOld in boTables)
            {

                CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ISCRTable boTableNew = boTableOld.Clone(true);
                boConnectionInfo = boTableNew.ConnectionInfo;
                boAttributesPropertyBag = (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag)boConnectionInfo.Attributes;

                // Change the attributes and QE_LogonProperties to an ODBC connection
                boAttributesPropertyBag["QE_ServerDescription"] = dbpath;
                boLogonPropertyBag = (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag)boAttributesPropertyBag["QE_LogonProperties"];
                boLogonPropertyBag["Data Source"] = dbpath;
                boLogonPropertyBag["Jet Database Password"] = "54321";
                boAttributesPropertyBag = (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag)boConnectionInfo.Attributes;
                boTableNew.QualifiedName = boTableNew.Name;
                boTableNew.ConnectionInfo.UserName = "Admin";
                boTableNew.ConnectionInfo.Password = "";
                boDatabaseController.SetTableLocation(boTableOld, boTableNew);   
            }
            r.VerifyDatabase();
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add it to your App or Web config as keys like:

```
<add key="ServerName" value="YourServer"/>
<add key="DataBaseName" value="WorkingDataBase"/>
<add key="DatabaseUser" value="DBUser"/>
<add key="DatabasePassword" value="DBPassword"/>
```

and call them in your code like:

```
Dim SERVER_NAME As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ServerName").ToString()
Dim DATABASE_NAME As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DataBaseName").ToString()
Dim DatabaseUser As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DatabaseUser").ToString()
Dim DatabasePassword As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DatabasePassword").ToString()
```

and for security issue you can encrypt the password and decrypt it.